# Django admin - add/change view divided into bookmarks

Tags: django, django-forms, admin

I have an article model with fields that I'd like to divide into categories represented by bookmarks visible on add/change view of my article, for example:
title, contents, category, author would be in the main category, publication start, end, creation time, and so on would be in the statistics category, and the other fields would be in the "other" category. Can I accomplish this without overriding admin views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allthough I don't know what you mean by 'bookmarks', I think what you're looking for is the `fieldsets` property.

For example:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('title', 'contents', 'category', 'author')
        }),
        ('Statistics', {
            'fields': ('publication_start', 'end', 'creation_time')
        }),
    )
```

More on this in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets).